# Change configuration's order

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My Project contains 4 configurations:

[image]

But the order sometimes leads to problems since everyone assumes the order to be Debug, Development, Staging, Release. Note that the same order is used in Build settings, project settings and basically everywhere.

Is there a way to change the order of the configurations?

(The order is not alphabetical since I have other projects with different ordering and the same configurations)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know this is proper, but I could change the order of the configurations.

1. Open `project.pbxproj` with Text Editor.
2. Search Text with `Begin XCConfigurationList section`
3. There are lists of configurations as below

```
buildConfigurations = (
    A48AF1752267044500EBCA41 /* Debug */,
    A48AF1762267044500EBCA41 /* Release */,
)
```

4. Edit this list as you like

Comment: It does change the order in most places, but unfortunatelly it doesn't do it everywhere, at least not in the build settings

Comment: In build settings, it seems to be impossible to change the order. Configurations are sorted in alphabetical order.